# Error with simple web service php

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services

Hi developers i am new to web services i wrote a simple php web service but i got 'Empty Xml'.
Here is my php code.

```
<?php

require_once ('lib/nusoap.php');
$server = new soap_server;
$server->configureWSDL('SimpleWebService', 'urn:http://webservicesoap/server.php');
$server->register("test", array('your_name' => 'xsd:string'), array('return' =>
        'xsd:string'), "http://webservicesoap/server.php", false, 'rpc', 'encoded',
    'Simple Add Function');

function test($your_name)
{
    if (!$your_name)
    {
        return new SoapFault('Client', '', 'Put Your Name!');
    }
    $result = "Welcome to " . $your_name .
        ". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP With SOAP";
    return $result;

}
$HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA = isset($HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA) ? $HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_POST_RAW_DATA);
exit();

?>
```

Here is C# code.

```
 Test.SimpleWebService t = new Test.SimpleWebService();

            t.test("Jawad Zeb");
```

Note: I have added the web refference and also wamp server is running.

Please help me solving this problem. Any help is appreciated.
Here is the screenshot of exception.
[image: Empty XML Exception]

Comment: Try to Put `global $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;` in the method

Comment: @too_cool can you please put a sample code what are you saying.

Comment: What does `if(!$yourname)` Checking ??

Comment: if $yourname is  null

Comment: removing this condition still gave the same Error.
function test($your_name)
{
  
    $result = "Welcome to ".". Thanks for Your First Web Service Using PHP With SOAP";
    return $result;

}

Comment: try this `$namespace="http://webservicesoap/server.php"`
 `$server->configureWSDL("SimpleWebService");`
`$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;`

Comment: No USE. @too_cool can you post a sample hello world php web service code which i just copy paste and check . ? i have followed several tutorials but at the end all give the same result . i don't know why....!!

Comment: Check this link and follow all steps http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84543/discussion-between-jawad-zeb-and-too-cool).